# how to parse DD-MMM-YYYY to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want a JS function that take the following format as input :

```
DD-MMM-YYYY
```

and return this format as a result

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

how to achieve that ? the problem also that the time part is not provided in the recived date

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: The only thing you can do is assume a time. Say, `00:00:00` or whatever you want. There is no way to retrieve anything concrete from just a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont use with Date Functions ?

```
let date: Date = new Date();
let fullDateAndTime: string = date.getFullYear() + "" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "" + date.getHours() + "" + date.getMinutes() + "" + date.getMilliseconds();
document.write(fullDateAndTime + ""); // Print YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

So you can check it with simple if (Month less then 10) :

```
let date: Date = new Date();
// date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() + 1 : date.getMonth() + 1
// Check if the month is less than 10 with ternary if
let fullDateAndTime: string = date.getFullYear() + "" + (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() + 1 : date.getMonth() + 1) + "" + date.getHours() + "" + date.getMinutes() + "" + date.getMilliseconds();
document.write(fullDateAndTime + ""); // Print YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

It will print just as you wanted ...

Comment: thanks but it returns the month at M format not MM format if i'ts less than 10

Comment: Her osfar !I was glad to help and good luck! If you can accept the answer to the community I would be very happy!